# Upload image to dropbox public folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload the image to my drop box public folder using javascript. Its only uploading the image name with extension - the image doesn't appear when i open it in dropbox folder.
Here's my code:

```
 reader = new FileReader({
    'blob': true
   });  

reader.onloadend = function () {
    var rawBytes = reader.result;

    $.ajax({
    url:'https://apicontent.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/Public/TestFolder/"' + evt.target.files[0].name + '"?access_token=MYTOKEN',

        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: rawBytes,

        success: function (data) {
            console.log('file uploaded successfully');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

 }
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(evt.target.files[0]);
```

Comment: If create any string like var str="This is test file"; and update my ajax "data:str" it uploads the string.

Comment: There's a thread here with some ways to do this: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207430886-Uploading-saved-local-image-file-using-Javascript-

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. This tutorial worked.